# Why Double.parseDouble(null) and Integer.parseInt(null) throw different exceptions?

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

The documentation says that there are two types of exceptions for `Double.parseDouble()` and one for `Integer.parseInt()`, but it seems inconsistent:

```
Integer.parseInt(null); // throws java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Double.parseDouble(null); // throws java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right: It's inconsistent. Move along, nothing to see here... ;-) The JDK library is very large, has grown over time, and has various inconsistencies. I have to admit this one surprised me enough that I felt the need to double-check your assertion and the actual behavior (in case it differed from the doc): http://ideone.com/18W8W8) But there we go.

As [JB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26818694/i-dont-know-why-double-parsedoublenull-and-integer-parseintnull-throw-differ/26818766#comment42207498_26818766), one clue to underlying cause of the inconsistency might be that [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) was in the JDK from the beginning, but [`Double.parseDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-) was added in 1.2. So perhaps thinking around being more specific about the issue changed between those two times.

---

SO won't let me post the answer with the link above without code, so:

```
try {
    Integer.parseInt(null); // throws java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Integer: " + e.getClass().getName());
}
try {
    Double.parseDouble(null); // throws java.lang.NullPointerException
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Double: " + e.getClass().getName());
}
```

Output:

```
Integer: java.lang.NumberFormatException
Double: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Agreed. As an indication, parseDouble() exists since 1.2, whereas parseInt() exists since the beginning. They probably decided that null should be consistently handled by throwing a NullPointerException in 1.1 or 1.2, but couldn't change parseInt() to maintain backward-compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

**parsed double**

```
public static double parseDouble(String s) throws NumberFormatException
{
    return FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(s).doubleValue();
}
```

`readJavaFormatString` will return null, that explains the `NullPointerException`

**ParseInt**

```
//...
if (s == null) {
     throw new NumberFormatException("null");
}
//...
```

That's written like that. Not very coherent but there is worse in the JDK.